# Error :Parse output of a command in windows command line file

Tags: windows, parsing, command-line, batch-file

**I am trying to parse the output of a command in a command line script**. As a start i have to first capture the output of the command in a variable ( i guess) . So here is what i have written so far:

```
FOR /F "tokens=2* delims=    " %%A IN ('wmic process where(name="javaw.exe") get commandline') DO SET VAR=%%B
echo %VAR%
```

where `wmic process where(name="javaw.exe") get commandline` is the command i want to execute and save the output.
But i get the following error upon executing this.

```
get was unexpected at this time
```

Any ideas why the error. And how do i proceed after storing the output in a variable. I am looking for a particular word say **"XYZ"** in the output and if that word is there i want to display a windows pop-up.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: It's a batch script or it's executed at the cmd line, but command line scripts doesn't exists

Answer (score 3):

The reason it is giving you an error is because the first `)` in the `for` loop is effectively ending the loop, then the `get` command is processed separately, which isn't recognised.

You need to use the caret `^` to escape the brackets and the `=`.

```
FOR /F "tokens=2* delims=    " %%A IN ('wmic process where^(name^="javaw.exe"^) get commandline') DO SET VAR=%%B
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Nope. Now i get "B was unexpected at this time"!!

Comment: Are you running from cmd line or batch file?

Comment: Then you need to use single `%`'s in the `for` loop, you use double `%%` for batch files. `%A` and `%B`, rather than `%%A` and `%%B`

Comment: +1 - but actually the 2nd `(` does not cause problems and does not need to be escaped. It is the first `)` that is causing the problem, and it needs to be escaped as you have shown.

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the syntax, but even then you will not get the desired results, as wmic normally responds with more than one line.

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
FOR /F "tokens=* delims=" %%A IN (
    '"wmic process where(name="javaw.exe") get commandline"') DO (
     set "line=%%A"
     if "!line:XYZ=!" NEQ "!line!" (
        echo The line contains XYZ
     )
)
```

And setting delims to space will split the line at the first space, even if this is in the path of javaw.exe.

Comment: can i search for a string directly in the output without saving it in a variable?

Comment: I added a solution which search for XYZ in each line of the WMIC output

Comment: ok. Suppose i change my command to "wmic process where (name="javaw.exe") get commandline | find "XYZ". Then there would be only one result in the output if any[i know]. Now what can i do? I mean how to check if the length of the output and so on if the length is more than zero display a popup..